# API-Call with dynamic URL - Observable undefined

Tags: angular, api, angular6

I have an app where I first dynamically load the API-URLs and then make querys to them.

If the App is running for a while that is very easy but at startup my API-Calls have to wait to retrieve the URLs.

This is my code in the service that makes the API-Calls. It depends on another service, called sls, that will fetch the dynamic API-URLs.

```
 queryFlights(body: FlightBoardApiCallBody): Observable<any>{
    if (this.getFlightsURL){
      return this.queryFlightsHelper(body, this.getFlightsURL);
    } else {
      this.sls.getServices()
        .map(s => s[GET_FLIGTHS_SERVICE_NAME])
        .switchMap(url => {
          if (url != null){
            return this.queryFlightsHelper(body, url);
          } else {
            return Observable.empty();
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

The actual API-Call happens here. This works when called from line 3.

```
private queryFlightsHelper(b: FlightBoardApiCallBody, url: string): Observable<any>{...}
```

In my controller I do this (same function at startup or manuall calls later).:

```
this.flightSubscription = this.f.queryFlights(body).subscribe((res) => {...});
```

At startup I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

If I call the function via the click of a button, the URLs are already preloaded. Therefore it is using the if instead of the else path and everything works fine.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong in the else-path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a return statement:

```
 queryFlights(body: FlightBoardApiCallBody): Observable<any>{
if (this.getFlightsURL){
  return this.queryFlightsHelper(body, this.getFlightsURL);
} else {
  return this.sls.getServices()  // HERE
    .map(s => s[GET_FLIGTHS_SERVICE_NAME])
    .switchMap(url => {
      if (url != null){
        return this.queryFlightsHelper(body, url);
      } else {
        return Observable.empty();
      }
    });
}
```

}